# Can you have more than 65536 sessions on an Oracle RAC database?

Tags: oracle

I put this same question on Oracle's community site but this site gets a lot of activity so I am posting here also. Apologies to anyone who is on both.

Other post: [https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4482456/can-you-have-more-than-65536-sessions-on-a-rac-database](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4482456/can-you-have-more-than-65536-sessions-on-a-rac-databasen%20have%20at%20most%2065536%20sessions%20on%20a%20single%20node%20database.%20%20If%20I%20had%20a%20two%20node%20RAC%20database%20could%20each%20node%20have%2065536%20sessions%20or%20are%20we%20limited%20to%2065536%20total%20for%20both%20nodes?%20%20Bobby)

On Oracle 19c you cannot set the sessions parameter to more than 65536 so I believe that means that you can have at most 65536 sessions on a single node database.

If I had a two node RAC database could each node have 65536 sessions or are we limited to 65536 total for both nodes?

Bobby

Answer (score 1):

Each Oracle instance in a RAC configuration maintains its own resources and sessions; you would be able to have up to 65536 sessions for each node in the cluster.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RACAD/GUID-59DEC066-5743-4EDE-9A02-E8896005F658.htm#RACAD818

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Makes sense but I would feel better if I could actually test it directly. The gv$session view has instance number and session id so it makes sense that there would be 65536 for each node. Anyway, I need a RAC instance to ramp up some sessions on. :)